# Prove that derivatve at point is bounded by 1

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

> Let $U$ be a simple connected subset of $\mathbb{C} $ such that $U\neq\mathbb{C}$. Suppose $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a holomorphic function such that $f(a)=a$. I'd like to show that $|f'(a)|\leq 1$.

It looks  a little bit like a Schwarz Lemma. I can (and proably have to) use Riemann's mapping theorem and take holomorphic function g, such that $g^{-1}:D(0,1) \rightarrow U, g(a)=0$ then I quess it is sufficient to take function $h(z)= \frac{f(z)-a}{z-a} $ and $h(a)= f^{'}(a)$ and look closely at a function $H:D(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ $H(z) = h(g^{-1}(z))$.But I can't get anythng out of it. Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: As stated, this is clearly false.

Comment: Could you be more specific about it? Any counter- examples?

Comment: All right, the simplest example may be $f(z) =e^z -e^a +a$ for big a.Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the simplest counterexample $f(z) = 2z$ for $a = 0$?

Comment: I think you mean $f : U \to U$.